# Oracle APEX 23.2.1 changing sessions and not showing alias in friendly url syntax

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have created a new page in Apex. I have two problems.

**1.problem **
When I press save and run page my app starts and shows in the url session = 123456789. When I press any other page in the navigation menu on the left side of the app then it changes session in my URL to some new numbers like 8584934682316.

I checked Target column in Shared Components=>Lists=>List Details options and all pages are defined in the same way. For example, 204  is the number of one of my pages =>
f?p=&APP_ID.:204:&APP_SESSION.::&DEBUG.::::

**2.problem **

When I run app some of my pages in their friendly url don't show alias of the page:

The one that run properly have URL like

https://myinstancelinkthatidon'twannashowhere/ords/r/reporting/extrareporting/mypagealias?session=1234500232

The one that don't run properly have URL like

https://myinstancelinkthatidon'twannashowhere/ords/r/reporting/extrareporting/210?session=1234500232

The difference is in mypagealias vs. number 210 that is the number of that page.

Any help would be good.

Comment: Asking  2 questions in a single post is not a good idea. What if discussion is needed on both questions ? That thread becomes unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to "problem" 1:
That is (most probably) because you are (1) working on the app as a developer and (2) the authentication scheme in your app is "APEX Accounts". The url that you have in the app builder also has a session (since apex runs on ... apex). So when you launch your app from the builder it picks up the session from the builder. Any subsequent page it will have its own session id - from then on the session id will not change.
Do the following test. Run the app without the builder open. Check if the session id changes. It probably shouldn't. I'm not specialist on apex sessions so won't be able to go into more detail.
If the auth scheme is something else than APEX Accounts you won't see this behaviour either (tested with SAML and I didn't get the builder session). But... why is this a problem ? What does not work because of this behaviour ?

Answer to "problem 2". If you want to discuss then I'd suggest posting a new issue. 1 question, one post. What is the difference between the pages that show the alias and the pages that show the page number ? Investigate to find out. That will guide you in the right direction. Do those pages have a valid alias - if you run them from the builder... do you see alias or page number ? But just like with the first "problem"... ... why is this a problem ? What does not work because of this behaviour ?